# data not inserted into mysql database via php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The Data is being correctly displayed so there is no issue with passing of data from the form hence there is an error i am unable to find.

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("property", $connect);

/* if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['comments'])){ */
$rs = $_POST['rs'];
$cr = $_POST['cr'];
$locality = $_POST['locality'];
$br = $_POST['br'];
$bth = $_POST['bth'];
$fr = $_POST['fr'];
$flr = $_POST['flr'];
$tflr = $_POST['tflr'];
$bu = $_POST['bu'];
$park = $_POST['park'];
$af = $_POST['af'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$query = "INSERT INTO property(id,sale/rent,com/res,locality,bedroom,bathroom,furnished_status,
            floor,total floors,builtup/superbuiltup,includes_park,available_from,details) 
          VALUES('','$rs','$cr','$locality','$br','$bth','$fr','$flr','$tflr','$bu','$park','$af','$comment')";

mysql_query($query, $connect);

echo $rs;
echo "<br>";
echo $cr;
echo "<br>";
echo $locality;
echo "<br>";
echo $br;
echo "<br>";
echo $bth;
echo "<br>";
echo $fr;
echo "<br>";
echo $flr;
echo "<br>";
echo $tflr;
echo "<br>";
echo $bu;
echo "<br>";
echo $af;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";


/*
  header('location:submitted.html');
  } */
?>
```

Comment: that's some bizarre looking code but nothing to help anyone identify the issue.

Comment: Take a look on php_errors.log or /var/log/mysql/error.log. I guess you miss some fields

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @user3529096: Atleast respond to the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on your sql syntax..

```
$query="INSERT INTO property(id,sale/rent,
                                        com/res,
                                        locality,
                                        bedroom,
                                        bathroom,
                                        furnished_status,
                                        floor,
                                        total floors,
                                        builtup/superbuiltup,
                                        includes_park,
                                        available_from,
                                        details) VALUES('',                                                                          '$rs',
                                                                        '$cr',
                                                                        '$locality',
                                                                        '$br',
                                                                        '$bth',
                                                                        '$fr',
                                                                        '$flr',
                                                                        '$tflr',
                                                                        '$bu',
                                                                        '$park',
                                                                        '$af',
                                                                        '$comment')";
```

Try this..

```
$query="INSERT INTO property(id,sale/rent,
                                        com/res,
                                        locality,
                                        bedroom,
                                        bathroom,
                                        furnished_status,
                                        floor,
                                        total floors,
                                        builtup/superbuiltup,
                                        includes_park,
                                        available_from,
                                        details) VALUES('',
                                                                        '".$rs."',
                                                                        '".$cr."',
                                                                        '".$locality."',
                                                                        '".$br."',
                                                                        '".$bth."',
                                                                        '".$fr."',
                                                                        '".$flr."',
                                                                        '".$tflr."',
                                                                        '".$bu."',
                                                                        '".$park."',
                                                                        '".$af."',
                                                                        '".$comment."')";
```

Comment: This should work and it is the proper formatting technique.

Comment: Hey @BlakeConnally : Explain How It is in proper formatting technique.

Answer (score 0):

to see the error use mysql_error():

```
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error();
```

You code needs to be secured it's open to SQL injection, also mysql functions are obsolete you should move to either mysqli or pdo and then use prepared statements it's much safer.

If you have your id is set to auto increment you don't need to add it to your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT QUERY** having column name `total floors`.

May be column name are allowed having spaces while creating table. But, While inserting it will show error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'total floors' at line 1

So, while inserting please enclose with backtick.

```
INSERT INTO property(... `total floors` ... ) VALUES ('',''....);
```

**Backtick**

[image]